# Android Checkbox text over button

Tags: android, android-layout, checkbox

I'm creating custom checbox with this style

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/bt_pick_true" android:state_checked="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/bt_pick_false" android:state_checked="false"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/bt_pick_true"></item>
```

I want to have text on that checbox to be over te this images, not on right side.

I try to add gravity on checkbox but nothing happend.

```
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
```

Comment: you want to set text above the checkbox it self

Comment: @mohammedmomn yes. and be in center of button (this drawable)

Comment: Is your text dynamic or static?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set it as background

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:button="@null"
    android:background="@drawable/cb_pick_style"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:text="Text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use android:button, use android:drawableLeft and give drawable_padding in negative. Like:

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:button="@null"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ur custom_selector_checkbox"
    android:drawablePadding="-20dp"
    android:text="one" />
```